# Unable to understand behaviour of inheritance in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance

I have created a parent class which has one property. 
Now i'm `inheriting` this class into my child class. It is obvious that member of parent class will become member of child class.
 So, when i change the value in child class, the same variable value is also getting changed in parent class.

I have used below mentioned code.

```
class SomeClass {
    var avar:String = "Hello"
    var bvar:String?

    func someFunc() {

    }
}
class Bclass:SomeClass {
    func myFunc() {
        self.avar = "Bye"
        super.avar
    }
}

let c = Bclass()
c.myFunc()  // "Bye"

let d = SomeClass()
d.someFunc() // "Hello"
```

Here output is **Bye** but it should be **Hello** as i'm not changing parent class member value. 
When i access with instance of `SomeClass` then it shows output as **Hello**

Few questions-

- Does it make copy of parent class variable in child class or refrence?
- super means i want to access variable of parent class then why value changed ?

**EDIT:** As per Frankie answer
In below scenario why it still prints "Hello".

```
class SomeClass {
    var avar:String = "Hello"
    var bvar:String?

    func someFunc() {
        self.avar
    }
}

class Bclass:SomeClass {
    func myFunc() {
        self.avar = "Bye"
        super.avar
        self.avar
    }
}

class Cclass:SomeClass {
    func myFunc() {
        super.avar
        self.avar
    }
}

let c = Bclass()
c.myFunc()

let d = SomeClass()
d.someFunc()

let e = Cclass()
e.myFunc()
```

Comment: Hint: In `Bclass`, `self.avar` and `super.avar` are the same reference to the same property.

Comment: but super supposed to access value in parent class then why it prints same value as self.It means it makes copy because when i print value from parent class directly then it shows "hello"

Comment: `Bclass` inherits `avar` from its parent class. There is only the one `avar`.

Comment: will it be copy or reference sent to child class?

Comment: Can you make your edit more clear as to what you're observing/asking/still confused about?

Comment: @iOSGuy I still don't understand your edit.  What do you mean by 'print' (you have no print statements).  What part/line of the code is not working, what do you expect it to output, and what is it outputting instead?

Comment: @iOSGuy **Bclass** creates an instance of **SomeClass** (some kind of copy of it), it does not change its properties. This is why it **c.myFunc** returns "Bye".

Comment: @Frankie I am using plyaground so don't have to use print statement.If avar = "Hello" is changed by it's child class to "Bye" then why Cclass still print value as "Hello"

Answer (score 4):

When you create an instance with `let c = Bclass()` there is one and only one instance created.  There is no 'super instance' that is additionally created, so the notion of copying or reference doesn't make sense.

The subclass merely inherits all the properties and functions of the super class, or more plainly, it inherits only what defines the super class.  Therefore `self.avar` and `super.avar` are the exact same thing.

**Example:**

```
class SomeClass {
    var avar: String = "Hello"
}

class Bclass: SomeClass {

    //imagine there is a (var avar: String = "Hello") here because it was defined in the super class

    func myFunc() {

        print(super.avar) //prints 'Hello'
        self.avar = "Bye"
        print(super.avar) //prints 'bye'
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

From the OP's edit:

```
let c = Bclass()
c.myFunc() //assigns self.avar = "Bye", therefore prints "Bye"

let d = SomeClass()
d.someFunc() //does not make any assignment in someFunc, therefore prints the assigned value of "Hello"

let e = Cclass()
e.myFunc() //does not make any assignment in myFunc, therefore 'e' looks to its 
           //superclass for the value since it was never overridden and prints "Hello"
           //It does NOT look to 'c' for the value because 'c' is a completely separate instance
```

Comment: can u now explain what is the issue ?

Comment: I am still confused ?

Comment: I am still confused ?.Why super.avar print bye.If it is going to print bye then what is the use of super.avar.in java i studied super.avar will print value in parent class.

Comment: The use of super.avar is so that you don't always have to assign self.avar a value just to get 'Hello'.  But the moment you override self.avar in the subclass and give it a new value, super.avar has that new value, because it **references the same object**.

Comment: i am not assigning value to get. I can get that by self.avar or super.avar

Answer (score 1):

A **subclass** takes ***all of the properties, function and methods*** of its **superclass**. The superclass is some kind of starting place / foundation for a subclass.

For instance, when you create a normal ViewController, you define it as:

```
class mySubclass: UIViewController{
    // UIViewController's variables, properties, methods, functions...
    // your code
}
```

You can imagine that all of the code from the superclass now lies inside the subclass as well. A good example of usage might be:

```
class Person{
    var name: String = ""
    var age: Int = 0
    var job: String? = ""
}

class John: Person {
     self.name = "John" // equivalent of super.name
     self.age = 26
     self.job = "Programmer"

}
```

You can say that the second class is some kind of customisation for the superclass, copying and changing its properties.